# DBAL Querybuilder copy and invert column

Tags: doctrine, dbal

With Doctrine DBAL Querybuilder, i can easily copy a column into another one:
`$qb->update('table')->set('col_1', 'col_2');`

But as both columns are boolean(resp. tinyint), how can i just invert `col_2` while copying it?

Comment: have you tried `set('col_1', '!col_2');`?

Comment: I did, yes. That gives me `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '!col_2' in 'field list'`